# How To Update MySql Database Values By One Click In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a web site. So , there is a table to show users. In my database, I stored 0 for the Pending and 1 for the Approved under Action column. If some user has 0 , Pending will be displayed in this table and if the user has 1 Approved will be displayed. Now I want to when someone clicks this Pending button, I want to update database value to 1. I tried it as below. But , when I click Pending button, it gives me this error -

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

And also I was unable to update the database value.

How Can I Fix this ??

View Page ( AdminPanel.blade.php )

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">

            <tr>
                <td> Action</td>
            </tr>

            @foreach($data as $value )
                <tr>
                    @if($value->action ==0)
                        <td><a href="actionedit/{{ $value->id }}"><input type="submit" name="pending" value="Pending"
                                                                         class="btn btn-warning"></a></td>
                    @else
                        <td><a href="edit/{{ $value->id }}"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Approved"
                                                                   class="btn btn-success"></a></td>
                    @endif
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
```

Controller. ( AdminPanelController.php )

```
public function actionedit(Request $request)
    {
        // Add Validation

        DB::table('users')
            ->update(['action' => 1]);

            $request->session()->flash('Msg', 'Successfully Updated !!');

            return redirect('adminPanel');

    }
```

Route.

```
Route::put('/actionedit/{id}', 'AdminPanelController@actionedit');
```

Answer (score 3):

You are requesting `get` not `put` change it to `get` http verb

```
Route::get('/actionedit/{id}', 'AdminPanelController@actionedit');
```

or use ajax to request as `post` or `put`

Comment: Now it's Working 100% Perfectly !! Thank U Very Much !! :D

Comment: I would expect more from you: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.* We can argue that `put != get` (is not a typo), but its so simple mistake that you could have posted comment and let OP delete the question.

Comment: @Kyslik : I appreciate your thought :)

Comment: @Amithash : Please revert your acceptance so that I can remove my answer. It is normal sense for route concept and not longer learning thing I found here. Also Please remove the question. After all you found the solution.

Comment: Well received critique, did not expect that. No matter the outcome +1.